# pygame - Screen size issue?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Edit: I've uploaded a screenshot of the bug; at the very bottom of the post. I'm still lost in regards to the origin of this bug, sadly.

I've put together a version of Conway's Game of Life in python with pygame, but I'm having issues with pygame's screen. The game only seems to occupy a portion of the screen, resulting in huge bars along the top and left of the window. I'm not sure how to address this. Here is the code. The images being used (located at the end of comp.py) are just two differently-colored single pixels.

stage.py:

```
import comp

class Stage:
    
    bg = [[comp.Node(0,0) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)]

    def drawNodes(self):
        for i in range(100):
            for j in range(100):
                self.bg[i][j].pos(i,j)

stage1 = Stage()
```

comp.py:

```
import pygame
import stage

class Node:

    onoff = False
    
    ns = 0

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def pos(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.n1 = [x,(y-1)]
        self.n2 = [(x+1),(y-1)]
        self.n3 = [(x+1),y]
        self.n4 = [(x+1),(y+1)]
        self.n5 = [x,(y+1)]
        self.n6 = [(x-1),(y+1)]
        self.n7 = [(x-1),y]
        self.n8 = [(x-1),(y-1)]
        
    def nCount(self): #neighbor counter
        self.ns = 0
        counter = {
            True: 1,
            False: 0
        }
        try:
            self.ns += counter[stage.stage1.bg[self.n1[0]][self.n1[1]].onoff]
        except IndexError as error:
            pass
        try:
            self.ns += counter[stage.stage1.bg[self.n2[0]][self.n2[1]].onoff]
        except IndexError as error:
            pass
        try:
            self.ns += counter[stage.stage1.bg[self.n3[0]][self.n3[1]].onoff]
        except IndexError as error:
            pass
        try:
            self.ns += counter[stage.stage1.bg[self.n4[0]][self.n4[1]].onoff]
        except IndexError as error:
            pass
        try:
            self.ns += counter[stage.stage1.bg[self.n5[0]][self.n5[1]].onoff]
        except IndexError as error:
            pass
        try:
            self.ns += counter[stage.stage1.bg[self.n6[0]][self.n6[1]].onoff]
        except IndexError as error:
            pass
        try:
            self.ns += counter[stage.stage1.bg[self.n7[0]][self.n7[1]].onoff]
        except IndexError as error:
            pass
        try:
            self.ns += counter[stage.stage1.bg[self.n8[0]][self.n8[1]].onoff]
        except IndexError as error:
            pass
        if (self.ns > 4):
            self.ns = 4
        if (self.ns == 2):
            if (self.onoff == True):
                self.ns = 3
        return self.ns

    onImg = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\#####\\PythonScripts\\conway\\tiles\\pink.png")
    offImg = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\#####\\PythonScripts\\conway\\tiles\\purple.png")
```

systems.py:

```
import pygame
import comp
import stage
import random

pygame.init()

win = pygame.Surface((100,100)) #surface for resizing

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600)) #target surface

def ruleFilter(node):
    n = {
        0: False,
        1: False,
        2: False,
        3: True,
        4: False
    }
    node.onoff = n[node.ns]

def turn(bg,x=100,y=100): #advance the game one turn
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            bg[i][j].nCount()
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            ruleFilter(bg[i][j])
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            if (bg[i][j].onoff == True):
                win.blit(bg[i][j].onImg,(i,j))
            else:
                win.blit(bg[i][j].offImg,(i,j))

run = True

stage.stage1.drawNodes()

for i in range(100): #randomly activates 40% of cells
    for j in range(100):
        x = random.randint(1,100)
        if (x<=40):
            stage.stage1.bg[i][j].onoff = True

while run==True: #primary loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            run=False
    
    turn(stage.stage1.bg)
    
    win2 = pygame.transform.scale(win,(600,600)) #resized surface
    
    for x in range(100): #update screen surface
        for y in range(100):
            screen.blit(win2,(x,y))
    
    pygame.display.flip() #update screen
    
    pygame.time.delay(10) #delay before next turn

pygame.quit()
```

Here is a screenshot of the bug in action:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `SCALED` flag in your `screen` parameters like so

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600)) #target surface
```

to

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600), SCALED) #target surface
```

Additionally, you can add the `FULLSCREEN` flag if you would like to fill the screen. This should remove the black bars and fill the display with the game. Hope that this helps you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice. However it doesn't look like the SCALED flag fixes it. I went ahead and took a screenshot of the bug and edited the post to include it. I'm still unsure what the cause might be.